# IE mobile only uses half of the screen

Tags: html, windows-mobile, ie-mobile

So, when testing my project on windows phone I stumbled across a problem I have not seen yet, neither know how it gets there nor how to fix it.

Image of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT3lv.jpg)

So the problem is that I specify that it has to use 100% of the width and height. With that, overflow is hidden so that there would never be a scroll bar.

Now when I look at the page in portrait mode, it does not use 100% of the screen at all. (see the image)

Then when I rotate the mobile to see the landscape view, it stays the same size but then just zoomed in. This causes there to be a scroll bar since the page is larger than the height of the mobile. But the page is still not the full width of the browser.

I can not reproduce this problem in Edge's emulator.
Neither do I have this problem in any other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your head section

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. Your answer did resolve the width. It now uses the full width. But now it does not use the full height. I tried adding `height=device-height,` but that does not seem to do anything. To see the image http://imgur.com/xgDaDSi

Comment: add height "100%" to your iframe